# How to prove this linear operator is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to solve this problem:
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FVZV.png)

I've tried to use closed graph theorem and I could not solve it. Could anyone give a solution or a hint.

Answer (score 0):

If $f_n \to f$ in $C(M_1)$ and $Tf_n \to g$ in $C(M_2)$ then $f_n-f \to 0$ pointwise and $Tf_n \to g$ pointwise. By hypothesis $Tf_n-Tf \to 0$ pointwise. Thus $Tf=g$. By Closed Graph Theorem $T$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser! But I'm not sure I understand "Thus $Tf = g$" correctly. This claim uses the uniqueness of limit right?